# Odd Ratios Change After Including Other Independent Variables... What does that exactly mean?

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, odds-ratio, ordered-logit

I am currently writing my master's thesis and I want to identify whether Austrians living in Vienna are more likely than immigrants in Vienna to become self-employed. In order to find out whether this is true I conducted an ordered logistic regression. The results are that they are more likely and according to the p-value the relationship is significant.

However, as I also find out the reasons for differences in the self-employment rates I further tested certain personality characteristics to determine whether these are responsible for it. However, when I run a second regression where I include these personality characteristics it shows me that two of them are significant and the odd ratio of the independent variable Austrian/Immigrants slightly decreases from 2.56 to 2.50. Can I argue from that that the personality characteristics are at least partly the cause of the differences in the self-employment among Austrians and immigrants?

Moreover, I conducted another regression where I distinguish between immigrants from developed and immigrants from developing countries. Here to OR are 1.85 for developed countries and 4.06 for developing countries. However, again after including the personality characteristics two of them are significant and after adding these the OR for developed countries increases to 2.07 and that of developing countries decreases to 3.53. What does this increase and decrease mean? Can I say from that whether these two personality characteristics are responsible for higher self-employment among both immigrants from developed and immigrants from developing countries?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Form a single unified model.  Form the contrasts you are most interested in, and test them.  Assume that ORs will change when you change the model.

Comment: What do you mean with that? That I should test the characteristics upon the Austrian/Immigrant variable and should leave out the probability to possess an entrepreneurial intention?

Comment: Make any comparison you want, from within the unified (big) model.  The `contrast` function in the R `rms` package makes this more clear.  See many examples [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/5.1-3.1/topics/contrast.rms).